# Make a query in two different tables and two different columns with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database with 3 tables.
`Artists`, `Albums` and `Songs`. They all have their `name` columns.

I have a query that can include the `artist` and the `name` of the `Album` or the `artist` and the `name` of any of the `Sounds` within the `Album`.

**How can I get all the Albums that match the search?**

I have tried the following

```
$album->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'sounds like', '%' . $name . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('artist', function ($songArtist) use ($name) {
                return $songArtist->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('artist', function ($songArtist) use ($name) {
                return $songArtist->where('name', 'sounds like', '%' . $name . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('songs.artists', function ($songArtist) use ($name) {
                return $songArtist->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('songs.artists', function ($songArtist) use ($name) {
                return $songArtist->where('name', 'sounds like', '%' . $name . '%');
        });
```

However, this only works for me when searching by `name` only. If I include the `artist name` it doesn't give any result for obvious reasons.

I would like to obtain all albums that include the artist and name if a query is made

Comment: From what I know the first argument to a `whereHas()` call should be the name of the method defining the relationship. That's not the case here, so that might be an issue for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, in my `Album` model there's a relationship method called `artist`. And at the same time there is also a method called `artists` in the `Song` model.

Comment: Ah I did not know you could chain them using the `.` notation, thanks for the tip!